# UILabel: Margin after using preferredMaxLayoutWidth with Autolayout

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, size, uilabel, margins

I have some weird margins in a `UILabel` when setting the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property of a `UILabel` inside a `UITableViewCell`. Do you know some behaviour like that?

I added the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` like that:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
   self.titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.titleLabel.frame.size.width;
   [self.titleLabel sizeToFit];

   self.shortDescriptionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.shortDescriptionLabel.frame.size.width;
   [self.titleLabel sizeToFit];

   [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

The Result is something like that:

[image]

As you see the title label has `14px` margins and I don't know where they are from.
I already tried to call `sizeToFit`, but that doesn't helped.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the label's width is set to the width of the storyboard or xib which it is instantiated from (check the width inside of layoutSubviews and you'll see that it is very wrong). You will have to set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` outside of this. What I have ended up doing is **setting `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to the width of the tableView minus any padding for the labels** (I used a constraint group for this), which should be the same as the cell width.

So you'll need the following in method you do your cell configuration in (called from both `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`